# scriptsharp pointer events/methods

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-canvas, script#

I need to be able to call setPointerCapture(pointerId) and msPointerCapture(pointerId) in order to properly implement pinch zooming on the canvas for IE. ScriptSharp does not recognize these methods since they are IE-only methods.

So is there a scriptsharp way of doing the following?

```
if (document.body.setPointerCapture) {
    document.body.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
}
else if (document.body.msSetPointerCapture) {
    document.body.msSetPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
}
```

[setPointerCapture on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-pointerevents-20141216/#widl-Element-setPointerCapture-void-long-pointerId)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using a script literal like so:

```
Script.Literal("var evt = arguments[0], cnv = arguments[0].target; if (cnv.setPointerCapture) {cnv.setPointerCapture(evt.pointerId);} else if (cnv.msSetPointerCapture) { cnv.msSetPointerCapture(evt.pointerId); }");
```

I am not happy with it, but it gets the job done.